# How to show a custom screen after biomteric authentication fails

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, authentication

I want to redirect the user to a custom app lock screen, where the user will enter the application password and be authenticated if the biometric authentication fails. But default iOS and Android shows the default system password/pattern popups. How can that be acheived in Flutter?

Currently i am doing this but i get error

```
 Future<bool> authenticateWithBiometrics(final BuildContext context) async {
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      authenticated = await _auth.authenticate(
        localizedReason:
            'Scan your fingerprint (or face or whatever) to authenticate',
      );

      if (!_biometricAuthenticated && context.mounted) {
        // Biometric authentication failed, navigate to the login screen

        await context.router.push(const PWRoute());
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The error i get is

```
Unhandled Exception: AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter.
```

And i get this error AFTER i encounter the default system password popups shown below

[image: I dont want the user to be redirected here, to this screen]
I dont want the user to be redirected here, to this screen

[image: When i tap on "enter password", i want to redirect the user to a custom screen]

When i tap on "enter password", i want to redirect the user to a custom screen

Comment: The button "enter passcode" is part of the system provided local authentication process. When the user taps that button they are directed to enter the device passcode. You can't do anything else until after the biometric and the passcode have failed